# How to determine if CKEditor is loaded?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How do I find out if CKEditor is loaded? I've looked through the API docs, but could only find the loaded event. I want to check if CKEditor is loaded, because if I load it a second time, my textareas disapears.

Answer (score 27):

The `loaded` event didn't work for me. `instanceReady` worked:

```
CKEDitor_loaded = false;

CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(){ CKEditor_loaded = true; });
```

Comment: There is no CKEDITOR yet, so how could I detect it? doesn't it fire anything when is ready?

Comment: Can you try putting it in JS fiddle?

Comment: If window would trigger an "ckeditorReady" would all be happy. I forgot to mention that I'm loading it on demand via ajax (in a parent tag with a PrototypeJS updater). It will be messy to paste all that but what it does is this: when the updater finishes (onComplete) it initialises itself and children. And in the relevant child's initialization I've done this: http://jsfiddle.net/yzxWv/2/

Comment: Update, I've just hacked and made it to trigger that at the end of the script and it worked as expected. But I now have problems that seems to be related to destroying it because if the updater is called again (like editing again that input) and CKEditor is saying "Uncaught The editor instance "goalEditor" is already attached to the provided element

Comment: You could use `|| {}` chaining for a one-liner to avoid the case of CKEDITOR or any of the other keys in the object heirarchy are not avilable yet, as follows:

`const isCKEInstanceReady = instanceName => (((window.CKEDITOR || {}).instances || {})[instanceName] || {}).status === 'ready';`

Answer (score 4):

```
var waitCKEDITOR = setInterval(function() {
    if (window.CKEDITOR) {
       clearInterval(waitCKEDITOR);
       //CKEDITOR.replace(...);
    }
}, 100/*milli*/);
```

Answer (score 2):

> I've looked through the API docs, but could only find the loaded event.

I don't know whether there exists a specific property for this - there might! - but you could use the loaded event to set a global flag. It's not really nice but would do the job.

```
// At the top of the script
CKEDitor_loaded = false;

// then later
CKEDITOR.on('loaded', function(){ CKEditor_loaded = true; });
```

Instead of a global variable, you could also consider setting something inside `CKEDITOR`:

```
CKEDITOR.flag_loaded = true;
```

This would be a bit cleaner.

Comment: And how do i un-load all the instances?

Comment: @Yvan I have no idea. Why do you need to do that?

Comment: because if I accidentaly load one twice, my page gets corrupt and needs refreshing. Since my app is completely AJAX driven, that's no good.

Comment: @Yvan you mean, when you initialize a textarea twice?

Comment: The textarea gets initialized a second time, when the user requests the page again. Let's say we have a blog and a registration form. If the user visits the reg form, no problem, if the user visits the blog, no problem, but if it visits the registration form again after visiting the blog, it's a mess, since the textareas get recreated. The user should refresh the page, and then it'll work again.

Comment: @Yvan I see! That's indeed tricky. Make sure you ask the question on the CKEditor forums as well, as far as I know, the developers hang around there frequently.

Comment: @Yvan you may also want to clarify your question to point out there is some Ajax loading going on. It's hard to tell at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

## If instance is not ready, the text set would be discarded

On initialization of the CkEditor (version 4 here), you should never set any data before the editor is ready to handle it.

```
// Initialize this._editor with replace

if (this._editor.status !== "ready") {
    this._editor.on("instanceReady",
        event => {
            event.editor.setData(data);
        });
} else {
    this._editor.setData(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post, but in my research it kept coming up. I am dynamically loading the `CKEditor` through `jQuery`. I didn't want to load it multiple times since things start happening, as you found out.

Simple solution:

```
if (!window.CKEDITOR) {
    // (not loaded yet, your code to load it)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone.

I also load a page snippet with CKEDITOR functionality via AJAX and as such I have experienced many of the problems outlined in this question. This is my solution:

```
function setCk(id){
if(window.CKEDITOR){
    var _instId = CKEDITOR.instances[id];
    if(_instId == undefined){
        CKEDITOR.inline(id);
    }else{
        CKEDITOR.instances[id].destroy();
        CKEDITOR.inline(id);
    }
}
```

}

On each AJAX response for this snippet I inject a script element into the head with a call to setCk(textareaId). The trick being to destroy any previous CKEDITOR instances for the target ID & re-initialise CKEDITOR after each AJAX snippet load.

Answer (score 0):

```
//creating instance of ck-editor
var yourInstance = CKEDITOR.instances.yourContainer;
//check instance of your ck-editor 
if(yourInstance){
      //destroy instance
      yourInstance .destroy(true); 
}
// create instance again
CKEDITOR.replace( 'yourContainer' );
```