# Clicking CKEditor content to show alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm trying to make it so that if you click the CKEditor's text area (where you type), it shows an alert, but I can't get it working and I'm not sure why.

Here's the JSFiddle: [**http://jsfiddle.net/C7N7r/44/**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7N7r/44/)

Please help!

HTML:

```
<form>
    <textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor1">Some text.</textarea>
</form>
```

JS:

```
CKEDITOR.replace("editor1", {});

$(document).on("click", ".cke_contents", function() {
    alert("CLICKED");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The problem

With [delegated event handler](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) you are capturing click events for any elements with class `cke_contents` that will ever exist in the document. And you are doing it right.

The problem is that `.cke_contents` is never clicked. It never handles `click` event. You can click it from code and your alert pops up.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(){$('.cke_contents').click()})
```

This is because of an `iframe` filling the full area of `.cke_contents`. Events are not propagated across frames, nor are they generated independently for the frame.

## How to solve it

You can set event handler inside the `iframe`. You can access its contents as it does not violate same-origin policy (both the document and the frame have the same `document.domain`).

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function() {
    $('.cke_contents iframe').contents().click(function() {
        alert('Clicked!');
    });
});
```

*[`jQuery.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) returns its content document for `iframe`, if it does not violate same-origin policy.*

Problem is that [`instanceReady`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3447803/2157640) is triggered for each CKEditor instance and the code above adds click handler to all CKEditors, therefore the handlers could be duplicated.

However, this can be solved by assigning the handlers more locally, just to the currently becoming ready editor:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(evt) {
    $(evt.editor.container.$).find('iframe').contents().click(function() {
        alert('Clicked!');
    });
});
```

This works OK as you can see on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C7N7r/45/).

## Side notes

Originally I did not get [jQuery event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and thought you are trying to add your event handler before the element with `.cke_contents` exists (your code is executed much earlier). Without event delegation you would need to use CKEditor API, namely [`instanceReady` event of the editor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3447803/2157640), only that way you can be sure you are adding your event handler to an already existing element. ([`$(document).ready(…);`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)) is still too early as you can see via `console.log($('.cke_contents').toSource());`.

BTW your attempt to replace your textarea with CKEditor manually just throws an exception as it already has been replaced. Try wrapping it in `try {…} catch (e) { console.log(e); }` to see it.

Comment: BTW the [automatic replacement of `textarea`](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/14-01-31-07-05/standard/samples/replacebyclass.html) was achieved using `class="ckeditor"`.

Comment: I've run into an issue. If I click within the CKEditor's body (`.cke_editable`), it won't issue the click event.

Comment: @Bagwell Works well in my browser (Firefox 17.0.11). If I click anywhere in the edit area of CKEditor, the alert pops up. It has no reason not to pop up. The event is just not propagated across iframes, which is why I made all the juggling with handler adding. Which browser do you use?

Comment: Firefox 26.0. Are you sure that if you click in the area where the first line of text would be that it pops up?

Comment: @Bagwell Yes, I really tried it. Both through the text itself and to the right from it. The alert always pops up. Pretty strange that it does not work for you. Are you trying it with my JsFiddle?

Comment: No, I've been trying it on my own server, but I couldn't see why it wouldn't be working.

Comment: @Bagwell Maybe a typo? Try it on JsFiddle and if it works, try to find the difference.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CKEditor API to do it in a simple way:

```
function clickListener(e) {
    alert("clicked")    
}

CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev){
    ev.editor.editable().attachListener(ev.editor.document, "click", clickListener)
})
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/up3HG/1/

Comment: You forgot about `.document` in `ev.editor.document` in your JsFiddle. But nice solution! +1