# Get id of element within ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Unfortunately I have to open a new question for this as I cannot yet add comments to replies (in foreign posts).

In this question ([Clicking CKEditor content to show alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469339/clicking-ckeditor-content-to-show-alert)) Palec posted a solution to get onclick events within CKEditor that works very well for me but as I hardly know jQuery I would need to know how I can get the id of the element (in this case the id of a div) within CKEditor using the code below.

This is the piece of code that I'm talking about.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function() {
    $('.cke_contents iframe').contents().click(function() {
        alert('Clicked!');
    });
});
```

Thanks for your help,
Pascal

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id of an element in native Javascript using

```
element.id
```

and in jQuery using

```
$('element').attr('id')
```

**Working Example:**

```js
// Native Javascript
var myDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
var myDivId = myDiv.id;
window.alert('Native javascript has found the id of the <div> is "' + myDivId + '"');

// jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
alert('jQuery Library has found the id of the <div> is "' + $('div').attr('id') + '"');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="my-div"></div>
```

Comment: I know how to get them normally, but how or where do I have to implement this in my piece of code? adding your code before the alert does not work, I tried it before with my knowledge and with your code again, to no avail.

Comment: forgot to add, the jquery function returns undefined

Comment: are you aware that I don't need to get the id of any div within the document (for which your code will work) but I need to get the div within the CKEditor that is at mouse position on click?